# Login Screen hangs after entering password

Tags: 12.04, login-screen

When I enter my password in the login box nothing happens. It gets stuck.  It was running fine earlier.  I have installed `gnome-panel` and `cairo-dock`, after which, I logged out, logged back in, and choose `gnome classic` session.  I also added a ppa from the webupd8.org to install the themes ([link](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/06/5-nice-gnome-34-themes-ubuntu-ppa.html)).

I opened Ubuntu Tweak tool, and changed the theme to `Evolve` the whole laptop stopped responding.  The keyboard and mouse were unresponsive.  So I was forced to do a shut down.  Now whenever it starts, I cannot login into Ubuntu.  I hear the fan noise, as its spinning very fast, when the laptop freezes.(Probably the CPU is running at 100%).

Please help me. How can I login back to Ubuntu? I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and have installed all the latest updates..

**EDIT**: I want to know how can I delete a folder from the `file system` using the live CD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks Mitch for your idea! I was able to fix my problem. I booted to my system using the live CD of Ubuntu. I mounted the file system in nautilus. Now to gain root access to the file system (of installed ubuntu), I typed this code in the terminal

```
sudo nautilus /media/"mounted drive name here"
```

I navigated to `/usr/share/theme`. Deleted the Evolve theme folder. Restarted the computer and now everything is normal.

Answer (score 3):

Using recovery mode can help you.  Use this mode only if your system is unbootable. It is also recommended that you make backup of important data.

> 1. Start Computer / reboot computer
> 2. Put your Ubuntu install CD
> 3. Make sure BIOS is set to boot from CD
> 4. Now booting will start from Ubuntu install CD
> 5. You will see various option screen - select Recover a broken system
>
> You will system is booting in to rescue mode; system will ask about
>   Network and other information. This is required to setup rescue
>   environment.
>
> Now you will prompted to select root partition or device.
>
> Next it will try to mount root device and it will notify the same.
>
> Now you will see common rescue mode option such as Reinstall GRUB or
>   open / execute a shell etc.
>
> Now you are in rescue mode.

**Source:** http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-boot-ubuntu-linux-rescue-mode/

---

To Delete Theme:

> Your custom themes are stored in the directory:
>
> ~/.themes
>
> Where ~ is your home directory path (/home/username).
>
> Themes are stored in their own folders under that directory, so to
>   delete one, simply delete the folder (which is the name of the theme
>   you want to remove).

**Source:** http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=453879 (post #2)

Now depending how you installed the theme you may be able to use the

```
sudo apt-get remove
```

command.

Comment: I am using a USB. Will the procedure is same? Themes are installed in /usr/share/themes

Comment: Yes, You have to create a bootable USB for Ubuntu through  [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, just follow steps and say what you got

1. Turn power on and hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> button
2. You see that the `GNU GRUB` comes, select **Ubuntu, with Linux ... (recovery mode)**,
   if you used burg, can't find recovery mode press <kbd>c</kbd> wich must open terminal(source: http://code.google.com/p/burg/wiki/InstallUbuntu)
3. After that you see its booting and the **Recovery Menu** comes
4. Select from there **root**
5. Write your password
6. Did you see that you got promt. If no don't continue, but if yes...
7. Write in there this:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove cairo-dock
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get autoremove
   ```

   if you think that this wan't help don't use that
   to change theme write this(source [is this](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1045076.html))

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gconf2
   gconftool-2 --type=string -s /apps/metacity/general/theme ambiance
   ```
8. Reboot, and say what you  get there

Comment: I don't think it is the cairo dock is the problem! I think it is the theme. Can I change the theme in the recovery mode? And yeah one more thing I have installed BURG and I have hidden the <b>Ubuntu, with Linux..(recovery mode)</b> using the Grub manger. So how do I enter in the recovery mode?

Comment: @Ravi , shure, just give me a min to edit

Comment: Hi, when I press 'c' a grub> prompt comes. There is no recovery menus at all. When I enter 'root' nothing happens! And how can I connect to internet in recovery mode?

Comment: not bad questuin @Ravi, i will say even good quiestion, sorry but  i don't know